# Omission of 'to'

Tags: ellipses

Arnold King, while writing a blog in *econlib*, wrote:

> The last thing he meant to do was call attention to the coercion behind the insurance function.

Should it not be:

> The last thing he meant to do was *to* call attention to the coercion behind the insurance function.

Is the second *to* an ellipsis? Or is the second way of constructing the sentence incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

In this instance, neither is incorrect.

I wouldn’t necessarily think of it as an ellipsis, since not all infinitives need a *to* particle in English.  It’s just a bare infinitive.

> I will make you do it better.

There is no *to* before *do*, nor can there be in this instance.  As a subject at the start of sentence, you need the *to*:

> To make it better is hard.

Or else you have to switch to the *-ing* form:

> Making it better is hard.

But I suppose there is little enough harm in thinking it elliptical.

Comment: Exactly. Some verbs -- usually very common and therefore abstract verbs like _make_ -- have more properties of auxiliary verbs, like taking bare infinitives (alternatively, deleting the _to_) the way _do_ and _can_ can do.

Comment: Thanks tchrist. @JohnLawler I'm sorry, I really don't understand your point. Will help immensely if you could give an example.